# How to rename a cq5 node name using GROOVY Console?

Tags: groovy, aem

I want to change the path of a template which is being used in so many pages. So if I directly change it from CRXDE it will a trouble. Can I do it using Groovy script ?

this is what I tried.

```
getPage("/content/project").recurse { page ->
    def content = page.node

    if (content && "/apps/project/templates/club" == content.get("cq:template")) {

        println("Good morning")
        page.path="/apps/project/templates/club1"

        println page.path
    }
}
```

This code just prints the list of pages where the template name is /apps/project/templates/clubs.

I want to change the name of this template to say /apps/project/templates/noclubs

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `content.set(name, value)` method to set new template property and `save()` method to commit the session:

```
getPage("/content/project").recurse { page ->
    def content = page.node
    if (content && "/apps/project/templates/club" == content.get("cq:template")) {
        content.set("cq:template", "/apps/project/templates/noclubs")
        println page.path
    }
}
save()
```